# Meaning of set superscripts $\mathcal{X}^n$

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

I know this is borderline computer science, but since it is the math I have questions about i decided to ask on here.

On slide 10 in the [following](http://adasys.sjtu.edu.cn/cit/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/20150101-Information_Theory_Chapter_5plus6.pdf) they state:

> Let $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ be i.i.d r.v. with generic $X$. A coding scheme
>   is
>
> $$\mathcal{C} : \mathcal{X}^n \to \mathcal{D}^{n'}$$

Where $\mathcal{X}$ is some sample space, and the same for $\mathcal{D}$. My question is then - what does the superscript $n$ denote?

Based on the context they use it in I imaging it is something like the following:
If we denote the $n$ r.v.'s as a vector $\mathbf{X}$, then $\mathcal{X}^n$ denote the set of
all possible realizations of  $\mathbf{X}$. However this is just a guess.

Comment: Isn't it a cartesian product?

Comment: Yes, it is. $\mathcal{C}$ is a function which takes $n$ arguments, each of them in $\mathcal{X}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathcal{X}^n$ is here the $n$-fold Cartesian product of the set $\mathcal{X}$; that is,
$$
\mathcal{X}^n = \underbrace{\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{X}\times\cdots\times \mathcal{X}}_{n\text{ times}}
$$
What this means here is that $\mathcal{C}$ is a function which takes as input (a tuple of) $n$ values in $\mathcal{X}$, and outputs (a tuple of) $n'$ values in $\mathcal{D}^{n'}$:
$$
\mathcal{C}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (d_1,\dots,d_{n'})
$$
for $x_1,\dots,x_n\in \mathcal{X}$ and for some $d_1,\dots,d_{n'}\in \mathcal{D}$.

---

Note that we can write either $x_1,\dots,x_n\in \mathcal{X}$ (all $n$ elements are in $\mathcal{X}$) or $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \mathcal{X}^n$ (the tuple of $n$ elements is in $\mathcal{X}^n$). These have equivalent meanings.